# Error at $q.all

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I've write the follow code in AngularJS for doing a multiple promise:

**CONTROLLER**

```
    var promisesSetUp = {
        setUp: getSetup(),
        brands: getBrands()
    }

   var getSetup = function () {
        var defered = $q.defer();
        var promise = defered.promise;
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: _config.WsUrl + 'api/SalesSetup'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            defered.resolve(response);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            defered.reject(response);
        });
        return promise;
    };

    var getBrands = function () {
        var defered = $q.defer();
        var promise = defered.promise;
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: _config.WsUrl + 'api/GetBrandsList'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            defered.resolve(response.data);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            defered.reject(response);
        });
        return promise;
    };


    $q.all(
       promisesSetUp
    ).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }, function (error) {
       console.error(data)
    });
```

When I execute this code I only have response of function getSetUp. The console output show:

**RESPONSE**

```
Object: { brands: undefined, setUp: data}
```

Anybody could explain me why I've only got response only of the first function?.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `getSetup()` you're resolving the promise with `defered.resolve(response);`
 While in `getBrands()` you're going with `defered.resolve(response.data);`

It seems that brands response is an Object, but doesn't have field data. Check that the field actaully exists in the response body in network panel.

You problably meant to resolve with `response` alone.

Also - if you're not modifying the responses at all you can simplify your methods:

```
var getBrands = function () {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: _config.WsUrl + 'api/GetBrandsList'
    });
};
```